# C# does an exception object contain the actual value that caused the exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

When Visual Studio reports the stack trace, I sometimes get things like "String value is not a valid DateTime". This question isn't about that error specifically, but as I look through the exception, I can never find the actual value. For example, is it "3", or is it "Hello"? I'm usually left to backtrace in the program to get it. My question is, does the exception object actually contain the value somewhere, that caused the exception, when we're talking about .NET calls?

Comment: Sometimes. Depends on the exception.

Comment: No, it doesn't, unless the one who throws the exception adds those values to the exception properties.

Comment: Fun story about putting the "bad" value in the exception. Before .NET v1 shipped it was possible to get an exception where the message was "you do not have permission to obtain the name of file c:/foo/bar.txt".  Super, thanks for letting me know what file name I'm not allowed to know.  Obviously that got fixed.  It's often a bad idea to put the offending value in the exception because the exception travels up the call stack possibly into low-trust code. Same reason why web sites do not display error logs to the hackers trying to break the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not. Generally it is not a bad idea - when throwing one's own exceptions - when possible to provide this in the message. But even standard methods do not. Simple like that.

Which is why some projects write extensive log files, logging all values on every functoin call (seen that), generating terabytes of information that then is quickly disposed.

Comment: In general, I believe it's bad idea, mostly because of security.

Comment: I'm thinking it's only a bad idea due to the way it's been implemented in the language. They should change it to make it easier on the developer, could easily be a release/debug build flag to include the values in the stack traces from .NET. It knows the value is invalid, so it should know what it is. Maybe I'll put in a feature request if people can see through the "security issue" aspect with a feature flag.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the design of the exception and how this exception will be caught.

If it can expose some sensitive information, you should avoid to include such values.

Otherwise you can consider to populate [Exception.Data IDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?view=net-5.0) , that can be very useful for error investigation.